# GROUP BY several hours

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table where our product records its activity log. The product starts working at 23:00 every day and usually works one or two hours. This means that once a batch started at 23:00, it finishes about 1:00am next day.

Now, I need to take statistics on how many posts are registered per batch but cannot figure out a script that would allow me achiving this. So far I have following SQL code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DATEPART(DAY,registrationtime),DATEPART(HOUR,registrationtime)
FROM RegistrationMessageLogEntry
WHERE registrationtime > '2014-09-01 20:00'
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, registrationtime), DATEPART(HOUR,registrationtime)
ORDER BY DATEPART(DAY, registrationtime), DATEPART(HOUR,registrationtime)
```

which results in following

```
count   day hour
....
1189    9   23
8611    10  0
2754    10  23
6462    11  0
1885    11  23
```

I.e. I want the number for 9th 23:00 grouped with the number for 10th 00:00, 10th 23:00 with 11th 00:00 and so on. How could I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it very easily. Use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) to add an hour to the original `registrationtime`. If you do so, all the `registrationtimes` will be moved to the same day, and you can simply group by the day part.

You could also do it in a more complicated way using `CASE WHEN`, but it's overkill on the view of this easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar a few days ago. I had fixed timespans for work shifts to group by where one of them could start on one day at 10pm and end the next morning at 6am.

What I did was:

1. Define a "shift date", which was simply the day with zero timestamp when the shift started for every entry in the table. I was able to do so by checking whether the timestamp of the entry was between 0am and 6am. In that case I took only the date of this `DATEADD(dd, -1, entryDate)`, which returned the previous day for all entries between 0am and 6am.
2. I also added an ID for the shift. 0 for the first one (6am to 2pm), 1 for the second one (2pm to 10pm) and 3 for the last one (10pm to 6am).
3. I was then able to group over the shift date and shift IDs.

Example:

Consider the following source entries:

```
Timestamp            SomeData
=============================
2014-09-01 06:01:00  5
2014-09-01 14:01:00  6
2014-09-02 02:00:00  7
```

Step one extended the table as follows:

```
Timestamp            SomeData    ShiftDay
====================================================
2014-09-01 06:01:00  5           2014-09-01 00:00:00
2014-09-01 14:01:00  6           2014-09-01 00:00:00
2014-09-02 02:00:00  7           2014-09-01 00:00:00
```

Step two extended the table as follows:

```
Timestamp            SomeData    ShiftDay              ShiftID
==============================================================
2014-09-01 06:01:00  5           2014-09-01 00:00:00   0
2014-09-01 14:01:00  6           2014-09-01 00:00:00   1
2014-09-02 02:00:00  7           2014-09-01 00:00:00   2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a CASE statement as below

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,registrationtime) = 23
     THEN DATEPART(DAY,registrationtime)+1
END,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,registrationtime) = 23
    THEN 0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query will give you what you are expecting..

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT COUNT(*) Count, DATEPART(DAY,registrationtime) Day,DATEPART(HOUR,registrationtime) Hour,
RANK() over (partition by DATEPART(HOUR,registrationtime) order by DATEPART(DAY,registrationtime),DATEPART(HOUR,registrationtime)) Batch_ID
FROM RegistrationMessageLogEntry
WHERE registrationtime > '2014-09-01 20:00'
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, registrationtime), DATEPART(HOUR,registrationtime)
)
SELECT SUM(COUNT) Count,Batch_ID
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Batch_ID
ORDER BY Batch_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add one hour to `registrationtime`, you will be able to group by the date part:

```
GROUP BY
  CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, 1, registrationtime) AS date)
```

If the starting hour must be reflected accurately in the output (as `9, 23`, `10, 23` rather than as `10, 0`, `11, 0`), you could obtain it as `MIN(registrationtime)` in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT
  count = COUNT(*),
  day   = DATEPART(DAY, MIN(registrationtime)),
  hour  = DATEPART(HOUR, MIN(registrationtime))
```

Finally, in case you are not aware, you can reference columns by their aliases in ORDER BY:

```
ORDER BY
  day,
  hour
```

just so that you do not have to repeat the expressions.